# Проблема с кодировкой при получении ответа HttpWebResponse c#

Tags: c#, кодировка, httpwebrequest

Получаю ответ от сайта следующим способом:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 
string result = "";
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251")))
{
   result = stream.ReadToEnd();
}
textBox.text = result;
```

В заголовке ответа поле Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251.
Пытаюсь вывести ответ, который пришел, в textbox, но выводится лишь 3 символа непонятной кодировки: **‹** , при этом result.Length выдает 33000, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена, добавлением строки для HttpWebRequest:

```
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
```